# my friend vs a friend of mine

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Am I right that "my friend" means that I have one or more friends and "a friend of mine" means that I have more than one friend?

Comment: No. Either implies only that you have at least one friend.

Comment: "My friend" can imply that you have only one friend.

Comment: @BillJ - it _can_ imply that, but does not have to.

Comment: Ok so can I consider that "my friend" = "a friend of mine"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's obvious to everyone, so it hardly needs saying.

Comment: @BillJ - but not obvious to the questioner.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I wouldn't say that. My comment simply means that is is possible.

Answer (score -3):

My friend means talking of about only one friend where a friend of mine means a friend among many friends.